# Are any of the planets in our solar system (other than Earth) inhabitable?

Tags: colonization, solar-system

I've watched a TV series on a group of people that build a community on **our neighboring planet, *Mars***, and after watching it, I started to wonder:

***Could something like this really happen in the near future?***

***Are any of Sol's (our sun) rocky planets actually inhabitable?***

Comment: Excluding Earth, you mean?

Comment: yes excluding earth.

Comment: None of the planets in our solar system could sustain unsupported human life in their current states. However mars, as well as several moons, all have to potential to support human colonies aided with technology, or even be terraformed to make it possible to live there unassisted.

Comment: Hi Imtherealsanic, and welcome. You seem to be asking about the real world, while on Worldbuilding, we're concerned with the construction of fictional worlds for use e.g. in storytelling, role-playing games, computer games, and the like. I'm going to migrate this to our sister site [space.se], where they are more likely to give you good answers about our real-world solar system. You may also want to check out [astronomy.se]. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: The surface temperature and pressure of [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus) are much too high for beeing habitable. The surface temperature of [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)) is too cold at night and too hot at day. The gas planets like Saturn, Jupiter; Neptun and Uranus have no surface to habit.

Comment: So you're saying only Earth can support humans naturally?

Comment: If natural support of humans prohibits the use of pressure suits with own breathing gas supply and without a heating or cooling device then Earth is the only planet to support humans.

Comment: @Imtherealsanic: there are lots of places on Earth were not even Earth can support humans naturally! 70% are covered in oceans, the North and South pole are too cold, some deserts are too dry, too hot, or both, very high mountains don't provide any food (and not enough oxygen), and so on. It really depends on how you define "support" and "naturally". Is clothing "natural"? Is canned food "natural"? Are boats "natural"? Oxygen tanks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No planets besides Earth have air that we can breathe, so in that sense, no other planets are inhabitable.

Of the eight planets, only Mars, Earth, Venus, and Mercury have a surface you could stand on.

Only Mars and Earth have surface temperatures low enough that a habitat could be built there with current technology.

But such a habitat could indeed be built on Mars. If, right now, advanced aliens made it easy for us to travel to Mars but gave us no help in surviving there, it would be easy enough to build a pressurized habitat that people could live in, with regular restocking of supplies.

Making such a habitat self-contained would require substantial research and development. The atmosphere is very thin and almost all carbon dioxide. The soil is not hospitable for growing crops. No particular obstacle seems insuperable, but an entirely self-contained habitat, even starting with Earth soil, has not been successfully created on a human-livable scale. (Biosphere 2 was a famous attempt.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about the rocky part there's always [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization_of_Venus#Aerostat_habitats_and_floating_cities). There is some very cool cloud city potential here if you can deal with the hurricane force winds.